# Simple ASP.net SQL Server database editor application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a website externally hosted, to which I have FTP access, however it is not a dedicated server so I can't directly connect to SQL Server. I have the database connection string from the `web.config` file.

I need to edit the database directly, but obviously tools like SQL Server Management Studio aren't going to work.

Is there a (free) simple database editing application available that will run directly alongside the website on the same server? I HAD one for classic asp years back but have always run dedicated servers since...

Comment: the hosting company should allow that.  if not get one that does, sql server mgmt is an absolute requirement.

Comment: I believe that you can connect remotely to your database.

Comment: @TMcKeown - "get one that does" is not an option, its a client's cheap-o site, it is where it is, and its staying there!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can access a database from a service like GoDaddy that is hosted with shared hosting through SQL Server. Check this link: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4978/connecting-remotely-to-shared-hosting-databases. GoDaddy says that you could even use the SQL Server Express edition to access your database directly and remotely but you must enable Direct Database Access when setting it up.